# Why should I use KStream or KTable?

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

I read but I couldn't understand too much. I read that I can use KTable instead of log compaction. Or it has many more features. However, I could not find a good example in this regard. I also couldn't see it in a nice source explaining the logic of work. Can you explain a good example of ktable and kstream and what can I do?

Comment: Maybe check out some talk recordings from Kafka Summit (https://www.confluent.io/resources) or on Youtube: https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=kafka+streams+introduction+ -- There are plenty on introduction talks about Kafka Streams that should help.

Answer (score 4):

As per my understanding, we should use `KStream` for the data which we want to receive from the source and are okay with data repetitions.

We should use `KTable` when we do not want to keep the repetitions of the records and we are only interested in the latest value for the respective key.

Kstream is continuous.

Answer (score 3):

A KTable is an abstraction of a changelog stream, where each data record represents an update. More precisely, the value in a data record is interpreted as an “UPDATE” of the last value for the same record key,

Kafka Streams is a library for building streaming applications, specifically applications that transform input Kafka topics into output Kafka topics.

KStream handles the stream of records. On the other hand, KTable manages the changelog stream with the latest state of a given key. Each data record represents an update in KTable.

KStreams are stateless whereas KTable is stateful.

Answer (score 2):

> I read that I can use KTable instead of log compaction

A KTable depends on a compacted state store topic. They are not exclusive options

> Or it has many more features

Well, why would you use a cache or Hashmap? The same answer can be applied to a KTable. The extra feature is that it can be shared and distributed across multiple instances of your application

---

You can do more research on the "Stream-Table Duality".

> example of ktable and kstream and what can I do?

A KStream is an audit log of all, or a filtered subset of events in the topic. It's hard to quickly pick out any given event

A KTable holds the most recent keyed event from a stream and allows for fast key lookups

A counter is the simplest example; You have a stream of events (say, words from hashtags)

```
#kafka is great
working with #kafka today
#streaming all the things
```

So, that's the **stream**. You then need to consume this stream into an aggregated **table**, parsing out and counting the hashtags, resulting in key value pairs

```
(kafka, 2)
(streaming, 1)
```

However, if you were to query the table immediately after the first event (before the table consumed the remaining events) you'd only see `(kafka, 1)`.

Comment: You explained without giving details.I couldn't quite understand what you said. You also said that there are many examples. However, you have not shared any links. Also, what I really want to understand is KTable. You deleted my KTable tags. I couldn't understand what you were doing. Thank you anyway.

Comment: It's off topic for Stackoverflow to provide external links, as per the [help center]. I gave you keywords to search for. What examples do you need that isn't already on the Kafka website? I deleted the tag because there are only like 10 questions on it ever, and [tag:apache-kafka-streams] includes KTables

Comment: The typical example is a bank balance vs a bank statement. Your balance is a table, that aggregates all transactions from the statement (the stream). As new transactions occur, the balance only maintains one number per account. From the stream, you can create fraud alerts or large transactions notifications. From the table you can detect overdrawn balances or insufficient funds

Comment: We probably won't get along with you. I already looked at the site of apache kafka if I could not understand. Everyone knows that everything is written on the official site. People write to Stackoverflow for further assistance.If we approach with your logic, everyone should look at the official document. Don't ask any questions here.

Comment: If you have any questions or need clarifications on the official Kafka site, open JIRAs, join the mailing lists for it to be corrected and fixed. Contribute back to the community.

Comment: And even if Apache site isn't good enough, Confluent maintains additional examples and documentation plus enterprise support and consultation or certification

Comment: Thank you for your attention. I will consider what you say.